# Tokenize a mathematical statement string

Tags: python, python-3.x, math-expression-eval

The function `tokenize` generates tokens from a mathematical string.

It can chain characters together to form longer tokens.

This can be used to build a parse tree, in order to evaluate the math expression.

```
def get_char_type(char):
    """ 
    Returns a string denoting the type of char. 

    >>> get_char_type('x')
    'letter'
    """
    operators = {'*', '/', '+', '-', '=', \
                '%', '~', '/', '&', '|', '>', '<'}
    if char.isdigit():
        char_type = 'number'
    elif char.isalpha():
        char_type = 'letter'
    elif char in operators:
        char_type = 'operator'
    else:
        char_type = 'other'
    return char_type


def tokenize(string):
    """
    Generates tokens from a mathematical statement string.

    >>> list(tokenize('3 + (4 ∗ 5)'))
    ['3', '+', '(', '4', '∗', '5', ')']

    >>> list(tokenize('x+=10'))
    ['x', '+=', '10']

    >>> list(tokenize('(729 + 4 * variable) ** 22 // 3'))
    ['(', '729', '+', '4', '*', 'variable', ')', '**', '22', '//', '3']
    """
    token_type = get_char_type(string[0])
    token = ''
    for char in string:
        if char == ' ':
            continue  # Spaces are not included
        new_type = get_char_type(char)
        if new_type != token_type:  # A new type of token has been found 
            yield token
            token_type = new_type
            token = ''
        token += char
    if len(token) > 0:
        yield token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible errors/suspicious statements

In `def get_char_type(char)`, you have repeated the statement

```
if char.isdigit():
    char_type = 'number'
```

twice. This is probably unintentional.

Note: The OP has removed this error in an edit before this answer was posted.

## Suggestions

Instead of explicitly checking for whitespace in your generator expression and using a `continue` to skip whitespace, you can filter the input string by a regex (regular expression) to remove all whitespace before you run the loop over the characters of the string. Kind of like this:

```
whitespace_pattern = re.compile(r"\s")
for char in whitespace_pattern.sub("",string):
    new_type = get_char_type(char)
    ...
```

instead of

```
for char in string:
    if char == ' ':
        continue  # Spaces are not included
    ...
```

This looks a bit better, although it might not be as performant as your original code. You will also need an `import re` somewhere at the top of your code.

Also, instead of that `if-elif-else` in `get_token_type()`, what about this?

```
def get_char_type(char):
""" 
Returns a string denoting the type of char. 

>>> get_char_type('x')
'letter'
"""
operators = {'*', '/', '+', '-', '=', '%', '~', '/', '&', '|', '>', '<'}
characteristics_of_token_types = {
    (lambda char: char.isdigit()): 'number',
    (lambda char: char.isalpha()): 'letter',
    (lambda char: char in operators): 'operator',
    (lambda char: len(char) == 1): 'other' #default case, if extending functionality, put any new case before this
}
for characteristic in characteristics_of_token_types.keys():
    if(characteristic(char)):
        return characteristics_of_token_types[characteristic]
```

Why is this better? If you want to add more types, it just becomes a matter of specifying a characteristic of a token type (via a lambda dictionary key), and a name for the type (as the lambda key's value). It makes a bit more sense to me logically, however, opinions vary.

Also, note that what I did above is somewhat along the canonical path of emulating a `switch-case` in Python, which is, in fact, a better fit for this problem than `if-else`. I was looking for something like guards in Haskell, as I've recently become a functional programming guy, but I've got to make do with Python, so this is what I could think up.

Finally, I did not bother making your token-parsing code more "functional" as I think the result would be more complicated than what you already have.

## Style

You have docstrings. That's a definite plus. You also follow the proper naming conventions for methods and variables, and there is adequate commenting, so no issues there.

However, a minor peeve - do you really need that line continuation when declaring the `operators` list? It doesn't look like you do, the whole thing fits in a line in below 40 characters all right.